# Div on front of other with hover

Tags: css

I am trying to make a username, password div appearing on front of other div with images. I tried different options but none seems to work.
When I make it work, the margin or padding messes things up.

```css
.imagesparent{
}
.images{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.joinus{
  visibility:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.images:hover + .joinus{
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagesparent">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="polohombrerojo.jpg" class="">
    <img src="trajenegro1.jpg" class="">
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="polohombreverde.jpg" class="">
    <img src="hombrepolo1.png" class="">
  </div>
  <div class="joinus">
    Join us to have the latest updates!
    <br>
    User:
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
    <br>
    Password:
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well please.

Comment: Done! If u need to change the images tell me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want like this ?

```css
.imagesparent{
}
.images{
 display: flex;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
}
.joinus{
  visibility:hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.joinus:hover{
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: blue;
}
.images:hover ~ .joinus{
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagesparent">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="">
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="">
  </div>
  <div class="joinus">
    Join us to have the latest updates!
    <br>
    User:
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
    <br>
    Password:
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I try to write on the User or Pass textboxes doesn't let me do that. Kind of flick and can't click on it D:

Comment: This positioning is true for you ?

Comment: And tell me please, what do you want exactly?

Comment: I need to take it down but yeah, and i want to make the join us div appear when the cursor is over the images

Comment: I edited my answer now, please check it. Do you want like this ?

Comment: Yes! thank you! can you explain what you did? so i can understand it

Comment: I would like you to accept my answer first. My English skills are not good but i try to explain now. I changed your joinus selector from `+` to `~`. Because I want show joinus when every image hover.  You can learn this selector from this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp). And I added hover to joinus class, because I want to entry any information the form. If i don't use this hover, I cant show it for entry

Comment: "*I would like you to accept my answer first.*" @OsmanDurdag is it against SO guidelines to ask someone to accept your answer like this. The OP doesn't have to accept any answer at all, so you should not make them feel that they have to do so.

Comment: My English skill are not good. I dont want this. Just i want say, if you love my answer, and if you will accept my answer, this is good thing. But i dont want say, you must do it. I hope you understand my sentences